# Regex to capture the staring with specific word or character and ending with either one of the word

Tags: java, regex

Want to capture the string after the last slash and before either a (; sid=) word or a (?) character.

sample data:

1. `sessionId=30a793b1-ed7e-464a-a630; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemSummary; sid=KJ4dgQGdhg7dDn1h0TLsqhsdfhsfhjhsdjfhjshdjfhjsfddscg139bjXZQdkbHpzf9l6wy1GdK5XZp; targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=122;`
2. `sessionId=sfdsdfsd-ba57-4e21-a39f-34; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList?id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf&memberid=273647632&iSearch=true; sid=Q4hWgR1GpQb8xWTLpQB2yyyzmYRgXgFlJLGTc0QJyZbW targetUrl=https://www.example.com/ mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=123;`
3. `sessionId=0e1acab1-45b8-sdf3454fds-afc1-sdf435sdfds; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/; sid=hkm2gRSL2t5ScKSJKSJn3vg2sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfvJZkDD3ng0kYTjhNQw8mFZMn; targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=343;`

Expecting the below output:

```
 1. itemSummary
 2. itemList
 3. ''(empty string)
```

Have build the below regex to capture it but its 100% accurate. It is capturing some additional part.

Regex

```
Url=.*\/(.*)(; sid|\?)
```

Could you please help me to improve the regex to get desired output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex in Java with a greedy match after `Url=`:

```sh
\bUrl=\S+/([^?;/]+)(?=; sid|\?)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xzll2p/1)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `Url=`: Match text `Url=`
- `\S+/`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters followed by a `/`
- `([^?;/]+)`: Match 1+ of a character that not `?` and `;` and `/`
- `(?=; sid|\?)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `; sid` or `?` ahead

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Used regex:

```
"^Url=.*/(\\w+|)$"
```

Regex in test bench and context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "sessionId=30a793b1-ed7e-464a-a630; "
            + "Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemSummary; "
            + "sid=KJ4dgQGdhg7dDn1h0TLsqhsdfhsfhjhsdjfhjshdjfhjsfddscg139bjXZQdkbHpzf9l6wy1GdK5XZp; "
            + "targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=122;";

    String input2 = "sessionId=sfdsdfsd-ba57-4e21-a39f-34; "
            + "Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList?id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf&memberid=273647632&iSearch=true; "
            + "sid=Q4hWgR1GpQb8xWTLpQB2yyyzmYRgXgFlJLGTc0QJyZbW "
            + "targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=123;";

    String input3 = "sessionId=0e1acab1-45b8-sdf3454fds-afc1-sdf435sdfds; "
            + "Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/; "
            + "sid=hkm2gRSL2t5ScKSJKSJn3vg2sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfvJZkDD3ng0kYTjhNQw8mFZMn; "
            + "targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=343;";

    List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList(input1, input2, input3);

    // Pre-compiled Patterns should not be in loops - that is why they are placed outside the loops
    Pattern replaceWithNewLinePattern = Pattern.compile(";?\\s|\\?");
    Pattern extractWordFromUrlPattern = Pattern.compile("^Url=.*/(\\w+|)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    int count = 0;
    for(String input : inputList) {
        String inputWithNewLines = replaceWithNewLinePattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("\n");
        // System.out.println(inputWithNewLines); // Check the change...
        Matcher matcher = extractWordFromUrlPattern.matcher(inputWithNewLines);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf( "%d. '%s'%n", ++count, matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. 'itemSummary'
2. 'itemList'
3. ''
```